# Pass argument to functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a very simple problem.
I want the upper variable to be changed only when the first button is clicked. However, it is always changed. I don't understand where my logic error is.

```js
export default function First() {
    const [first, setFirst] = useState('1')

    const test = (a) => {
        setFirst(a)
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{first}</h1>
            
            <Second onClick={test}/>
        </div>
    )
}


export default function Second( {onClick}) {
    const [second, setSecond] = useState('2')

    const  change = () => {
        second == '2' ? setSecond('1') : setSecond('2')
        console.log('2')
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <h1 style={{color:"green"}}>{second}</h1>

            <button onClick={change}>Test</button>
            <br/>
        <button onClick={onClick(second)}>Herz</button>
            <br/>
            {/* <button onClick={onClick(judas)}>Klick</button> */}

        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
onClick={onClick(second)}
```

This says to immediately call `onClick(second)`, and pass its return value into the `onClick` prop. Assuming the return value is `undefined`, nothing will happen later when the click occurs.

Instead, do this:

```
onClick={() => onClick(second)}
```

With that code, you are creating a new function and passing that function into `onClick`. Later, when the click occurs, your function will be called and it calls `onClick(second)`